# custom page in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We are currently working on small SharePoint project.

As per our requirement, we need to implement custom check in page with additional drop down list to select File status.

Would like to know whether we can customize default check in page? If yes, How? How to redirect to custom page?

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that what is the purpose of applying the metadata at the check-in status? Can this be a metadata property of the document? And if so it can easily be set in most office clients inside the document bar. Allowing them to retain their built in office client functionality. If this isn't the case. I would suggest using the Client Side Object Model to build a custom action that sets this value and then checks the file in. It would be much easier than creating custom action pages